# Retain time series data with duration of one second in R programming

Tags: r

So I have a time series data which is captured at every 15 - 18 milliseconds as shown below.

```
    tts <- ("10:49:56:459524", "10:49:56:580531", "10:49:56:720539","10:49:56:861547", "10:49:57:004555", "10:49:57:145563"......)
```

My question is how do I handle this data where I can retain only data with 1-second duration as shown below.

```
    delta_tts
    10:49:56
    10:49:57
    ....
```

I thought of trimming the time format to hh:mm: ss but couldn't do it.

Comment: something like this? `unique(sapply(strsplit(tts, ':'), function(i)paste(i[1:3], collapse = ':')))`...or with regex `gsub(":*\\w*$", "", tts)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we treat them as strings, we can split and get the first 3 elements, or we can use simple regex, i.e.

```
sapply(strsplit(tts, ':'), function(i)paste(i[1:3], collapse = ':'))

#Or with Regex,

gsub(":*\\w*$", "", tts)
```

Wrap both statements in `unique()` to get the unique times.

Answer (score 0):

As it is a time series data we can treat them as `POSIXct` objects and then use `format` to get data in required form

```
format(as.POSIXct(tts, format = "%T"), "%T")
#[1] "10:49:56" "10:49:56" "10:49:56" "10:49:56" "10:49:57" "10:49:57"
```

Or with `strptime`

```
format(strptime(tts, format = "%T"), "%T")
```

**data**

```
tts <- c("10:49:56:459524", "10:49:56:580531", "10:49:56:720539",
         "10:49:56:861547", "10:49:57:004555", "10:49:57:145563")
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `substr`

```
substr(tts, 1, 8)
#[1] "10:49:56" "10:49:56" "10:49:56" "10:49:56" "10:49:57" "10:49:57"
```

---

Or using `sub`

```
sub(":[^:]*$", "", tts)
```

#### data

```
tts <- c("10:49:56:459524", "10:49:56:580531", "10:49:56:720539",
     "10:49:56:861547", "10:49:57:004555", "10:49:57:145563")
```